# Angular PrimeNG Menu error "Module not found"

Tags: angular, primeng, menubar

I have tried all solutions in this thread, but still can't figure this out.

I am trying to use PrimeNG Menu.

In `app.module.ts` imported `MenubarModule`: `import {  MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';`

In `app.component.ts` imported `MenuItem` and so on as per `PrimeNG` instructions.

Yet while compiling i am getting an error for app.component.ts:

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'primeng/menubar/menubar'"

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gportal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.14",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.14",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^11.2.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^10.0.0-rc.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1000.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.14",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your package.json ?

Comment: are you able to use another module from primeng in your current project?

Comment: Yes, i can use other components.

Comment: @Natasha can you post update code in stackblitz

Comment: Hi Pardeep, I re-checked  if i can use other modules from primeNG  - no, i can't.  Input box gives me the same error.  Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the latest version of Primeng/Angular. So your imports should look like -

```
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';
```

You don't need to import `Menubar`,
For more information check out here - https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar

PS: Here you can compare your code with the code which is working (Stackblitz Example)

Comment: Yes, i am using the latest PrimeNG.  I saw and compared the StackBlitx PrimeNG example.  Even if it's all seems the same I am getting: "ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'primeng/menubar/menubar'"

Comment: not sure what's wrong, Might be there is something wrong with you PrimeNg module, if possible can you try to uninstall and install it again (From package.json as well)

Comment: Because, if Stackblitz is working then probably issue is with some other code exist on your codebase